# How can I make a cookie available before a fetch request?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, fetch-api

I'm setting an access token as a cookie for use in a data fetch. The data fetch works if the cookie is already assigned, but not on first render. The problem seems to be that the data fetch is running before the cookie is set. How can I go about getting the data fetch to wait for the cookie to be set?

Setting the token cookie:

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';    

useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/api/token')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      Cookies.set("TOKEN", data.access_token})
    })
}, [])
```

/api/token.js:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {

 const result = await fetch(`url`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      accept: 'application/json'
    }
  });
  const data = await result.json()
  res.status(200).json(data)
}
```

fetching data:

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false)
const [data, setData] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  setLoading(true)
  fetch('/api/data')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
    })
  } 
}, [])
```

/api/data.js:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {

  const token = req.cookies['TOKEN']

  if (token){
    const result = await fetch(`url`, {
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      }
    });
    const data = await result.json()
    res.status(200).json(data)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before each request, you  should check if your token in your cookie is defined. If not, you should await your call to `/api/token` before making any request and then set your cookies and your headers.

For my part, I'm used to using axios and taking advantage of its interceptors to do that and avoid having to do it in all requests.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    if (Cookies.get('token')) {
      return {
        ...config,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get('token')}`,
        },
      };
    }
    try {
      const token = await axios('/api/token');
      Cookies.set('token', token);
      return {
        ...config,
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      };
    } catch (_e) {
      return config;
    }
  },
  (err) => err,
);
```